# SQL COUNT - Advance, get the total of each record

Tags: sql, count

I have a table like below
Title        category_ide        new_date 
**Item A         1                        1**
Item A        2                        2
Item A         3                        3
**Item B         5                        1**
Item B         3                        2
Item B         2                        3
**Item C         7                        1**
Item C         2                        2
Item C         2                        3
Item C         2                        4
Item C         2                        1
**Item D         9                        2**
Item D         2                        3
Item D         2                        4

I want the result after query, but I have tried many time, get the latest of each Title, with 'new_date' is min follow of each Item
Title        category_ide        new_date 
Item A         1                        1
Item B         5                        1
Item C         7                        1
Item D         9                        2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.*
from your_table t
inner join
(
   select title, min(new_date) as mdate
   from your_table
   group by title
) x on x.title = t.title and x.mdate = t.new_date
```